# Run bash script faster

Tags: bash, concurrency

I have the script below, that takes a `.csv` file as an argument, which contains tens of thousands of filenames. What it does, is to read each filename, find it in my MongoDB, extract that file and then store it in the current directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

MONGO_DATABASE="db"
MONGO_HOST="127.0.0.1"
MONGO_PORT="9999"
DATABASE_USERNAME="user"
DATABASE_PWD="pwd"

while read -r filename; do
    sudo mongofiles -h $MONGO_HOST -d $MONGO_DATABASE -u $DATABASE_USERNAME -p $DATABASE_PWD --quiet get "$filename"
done < "$1"
```

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to speed things up, because it does take quite some time to finish! Is there any kind of parallelism I could do? I have very little experience with `bash` so I'm not sure what I could do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is `xargs`:

```
xargs <"$1" -d$'\n' -P$(nproc) -n1 sudo mongofiles -h "$MONGO_HOST" -d "$MONGO_DATABASE" -u "$DATABASE_USERNAME" -p "$DATABASE_PWD" --quiet get
```

`xargs` reads the input line by line and passes each line as the argument to the process. The `-d$'\n'` specifies lines are separated by newline, but also that `xargs` does not interprete spaces and quotes. The `-n1` tells xargs to run the command for each line/argument. The `nproc` is a linux utility to get the number of cpus, and that option is passed to `-P` - which specifies the number of processes to run concurrently.

Comment: So all I should do is this? `while read -r filename; do
    xargs <"$1" -d$'\n' -P$(nproc) -n1 sudo mongofiles -h $MONGO_HOST -d $MONGO_DATABASE -u $DATABASE_USERNAME -p $DATABASE_PWD --quiet get "$filename"
done < "$1"`?

Comment: `xargs` by itself reads the file line by line and runs the command specified - much like your `while read`. So just instead of the `while read`, you remove it, you just run `xargs ... mongofiles`. Try it in your shell, for example `printf "%s\n" a b c | xargs -t -n1 printf "Thel ine is: %s\n"`. More info at [man xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) and various resources on the net. The `-t`option to xargs is helpful in debugging.

Comment: It's actually 3 times faster than my initial script!!! AMAZING!! Thank you! What would happen if I increase the `-P` argument? Right now, with the `nproc` utility it runs on 4... Would it improve if I hard-code it to 8 or is 4 the cap?

Comment: It runs that many processes as specified concurently, for 8 it will run 8 processes in parallel. Sometimes I do like `-P$(( $(nproc) * 2 ))` for really short processes. The best setting is of course dependent on your specific case, on specific work(-load).